# C# Listbox / foreach loop question

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of data that is put inside a listbox.  Using the string.substring() method I need to go back in and take some data back for some calculations (average, high score, and low score).  I created a method called "calcStats" to calculate this data for me.  I am totally stuck on this foreach loop.  How can I find these values?  Can someone make some helpful suggestions on what I should do or create a brief example so I can learn what to do?

I understand now why the average was not working.  What would I do from here to "allow" single digits and double digits?

```
 private void calcStats()
    {
        string value;
        int value2;
        int total = 0;
        decimal adverage;
        decimal high;
        decimal low;


        lblHigh.Text = Convert.ToString(0);



        foreach (string itemInList in lstBox.Items)
        {
            value = (itemInList.Substring(50, 3));
            value2 = int.Parse(value);

            total += (value2);




        }

       adverage = total/(lstBox.Items.Count);

       lblAdverage.Text = Convert.ToString(adverage);




    }
```

Comment: You are almost there - you have the average, now high score and low score you can determine with a simple `if` to check whether the current score is higher than the high score so far, then make it your high score, the opposite for the low score.

Comment: I see you edited the original question when provided an answer to why the average doesn't work.  That's kind of bad practice and not how this site is supposed to work because now you've made the answers that fix your average problem look out of context.  Leave your original question as is and start a new question (because you do have a new question) or ask in comments.

Comment: Thanks Pete, I am new to this site.  Makes sense :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775230/computing-average-high-score-low-score-using-foreach-loop

Comment: 1) Your count++ is only executed once, it is always 1; should be in the loop, 2) You are only taking 2 characters, which means "100" gets turned into "10".  That's why you got 60 = (10+50) / 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are countless errors in your code.  For starters, you are getting an average of 60 because when you add 50 and 100 its actually only adding 50 and 10 then dividing by 1.  Watch:

```
    foreach (string itemInList in lstBox.Items)
    {
        value = decimal.Parse(itemInList.Substring(50, 2)); //This line truncates your score of 100 to 10
        total += (value);
    }
    count++; //This line only runs once.  So count is = 1 in the next line
    adverage = (total) / (count); //Since the '100' was truncated to 10, the total of 50 + 100 is 60.  Divide that by count which is only 1 and that's how you get 60.
```

To fix this, you could move the count++ up inside of the `foreach` loop.  Alternatively, you can divide by `lstBox.Items.Count` and eliminate the variable count:

```
    foreach (string itemInList in lstBox.Items)
    {
        value = decimal.Parse(itemInList.Substring(50, 2));
        total += (value);
    }
    adverage = (total) / lstBox.Items.Count;
    lblAdverage.Text = Convert.ToString(adverage);
```

That code snippet gets you exactly what you want.  The only problem is that it won't work with single digit scores or triple digit scores (100).

As far as keeping track of high score the general method for that would be to put the very first score into a temporary variable which you already have, `high`.  Whenever you parse out a new score, check it with the score in high.  If the new score is lower, then do nothing.  If the new score is higher, assign it to high and move on.  Same exact thing for low score just reverse logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good chance for you to learn how to use the debugger - look at the debug menu, learn what "toggle breakpoint", "step in", "step over", "continue" mean, learn how to "watch variables".

Try googling "debug visual studio" etc.

By the time you've learn to do these things, you should be able to figure out what's wrong with your program fairly easily, and you'll have learned how to figure that out for any other program that you write in the future.

Believe me, this is not the first program you write that will not work correctly right away :)

And also try out these commands - "select all" - "cntrl-a" and "format" - "cntrl-k cntrl-d" - this will format your whole document.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775230/computing-average-high-score-low-score-using-foreach-loop

Answer (score 0):

You should debug as Larry says, but I bet this would help

```
       adverage = total / lstBox.Items.Count;
```

One of the the most important things in programming is knowing the api (or in the case the common runtime library).  There is no reason to count the number of items when the object itself will tell you.