# Computing Average, High Score, Low Score using foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have the following code.  How would I make both one and two digit percentages work and not cause an exception?

```
private void calcStats()
{
    string value;
    int value2;
    int total = 0;
    decimal adverage;
    decimal high;
    decimal low;

    lblHigh.Text = Convert.ToString(0);

    foreach (string itemInList in lstBox.Items)
    {
        value = (itemInList.Substring(50, 3));
        value2 = int.Parse(value);

        total += (value2);
    }

   adverage = total/(lstBox.Items.Count);

   lblAdverage.Text = Convert.ToString(adverage);
}
```

Comment: Basically I am pulling information out of a listbox.  I am pulling percentages (values from 1-100) and I need to convert them to integers to do some calculations.

Comment: If I have a two digit percentage, it will read "15 " and when I try to convert it will cause an error.

Comment: @Mitch I am going to reference his original question here because it gives more context. I also answered this question using information from his other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774918/c-listbox-foreach-loop-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem this time is in another part of your code.  In your `btnAdd_Click` method you have a code snippet like this:

```
    //Add the data elements to the row
    row = name.ToString().PadRight(25);
    row += ID.ToString().PadRight(25);
    row += score.ToString();
```

You need to pad the score as well:

```
    //Add the data elements to the row
    row = name.ToString().PadRight(25);
    row += ID.ToString().PadRight(25);
    row += score.ToString().PadRight(3);
```

Without the `PadRight(3)` Your single and two digit scores would throw an exception because that single digit was at the 50th position and there was nothing to read after that single digit.  By padding it, you know have all 3 possible scores (single, double, triple digits) account for.  The parse function will take care of the whitespace and just give you the number whether it's 1, 10, or 100.

Comment: This causes another error.  The method I created is already capturing "100" for example.  If the percentage was 59 it would capture "59 ".

Comment: I don't know what to tell you.  I have the code running on my computer and it properly calculates an average of 55.66 on scores of 8, 100, and 59.  I am not sure what else I can do for you.  You need to step through your code with the debugger and figure out where exactly your problem is.

Comment: @Brandon: don't forget to vote up and accept Pete's answer if it helped you.